# How to avoid duplicating work across bazel configurations?

Tags: bazel

I'm working on a bazel project which uses many tools that are built within bazel as inputs to the execution of actions. Since these tools are built in an 'exec' configuration they depend on libraries which are built in the same 'exec' configuration and in addition I end up building the libraries in the 'target' configuration (as that is what I'm trying to validate builds). In my normal case these two configurations are both my host machine where bazel is running. In this scenario I would like to be able to avoid building all these libraries twice, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that. When trying to figure out if I could make the configurations match exactly it seems that I couldn't because there is the 'build option': `//command_line_option:is exec configuration` which is different across the two.

Is this possible by approaching the problem in a different way or do I just have to deal with compiling all my code twice?

Comment: You sound like "I want to build my code in two modes, but only once". If there are distinct configurations, then you probably want to build it twice. Your statement is contradictory, because that is why the configurations exists: to build a different output from the same code. Could you clarify which programming language you use, and how these two configurations affect flags, which are passed to the compiler?

Comment: The language is my own, "YASPL" (https://github.com/endobson/yaspl2). In the case where I am cross compiling i.e. an execution platform that is (darwin/mach-o) and a target platform that is (linux/ELF) then yes I need to build different binaries. But in the situation where the execution and target platforms are similar enough where the actions should be exactly the same, I would like to avoid double compiling. The issue is that the it seems that the configurations differ because one is an execution configuration and one is a target configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option, `--nodistinct_host_configuration`, that will collapse the target and host configurations. However, it is ineffective against the exec configuration. Additionally, Bazel upstream has indicated that this option is not really supported. (For instance, see https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5572.)

Allowing configuration flexibility while keeping the amount of duplicate work done under control is a thorny problem that is on [upstream's roadmap](https://bazel.build/roadmaps/configuration.html#efficiency) to address better in the future.

Comment: That doesn't change the exec configuration(s) it only seems to unify the target and host configuration. Following the roadmap I got to https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6526 which is probably the tracking issue for the whole relevant effort.